# Django class based views - threading issue?

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I think I'm experiencing a threadding issue with the Django class-based views I have written.

After launching the application, the UpdateView functions fine until CreateView is called/visited. Then subsequent UpdateViews populate the 'code' field with the value generated in the get_initial method of CreateView.

The problem only shows itself on the web server, and not when using the development runserver command.

E.g. if an instance of MyObject has a code of '123', then visiting the UpdateView shows the code in the form as '123'. After visiting a page which calls CreateView, a new code is generated by get_initial(), say '456'. From then on, visiting any url which calls UpdateView shows '456' in the form instead of the instances actual code.

Sample myproject.app.views.myobject view classes:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views import generic
from myproject.app.forms import MyObjectForm
from myproject.app.models import MyObject


class EditMixin(generic.base.View):
    form_class = MyObjectForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        if not self.object.pk:
            self.object.created_by = self.request.user
        self.object.updated_by = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Object saved.')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


class CreateView(EditMixin, generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = MyObject

    @method_decorator(permission_required('app.add_myobject'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(CreateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(CreateView, self).get_initial()
        #TODO: proper auto-generation of code
        myobject = MyObject.objects.order_by('-code')[0]
        code = int(myobject.code) + 1
        initial.update({'code': str(code)})
        return initial


class UpdateView(EditMixin, generic.edit.UpdateView):
    @method_decorator(permission_required('app.change_myobject'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UpdateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyObject.objects.filter(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Url Patterns:

```
from myproject.app.views import myobjects


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', myobjects.ListView.as_view(), name='myobject_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$', myobjects.DetailView.as_view(),
        name='myobject_detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[\d]+)/edit$', myobjects.UpdateView.as_view(),
        name='myobject_edit'),
    url(r'^new$', myobjects.CreateView.as_view(),
        name='myobject_new'),
)
```

Can anyone help explain where I might be causing the threadding issue, and the best practice to avoid this?

Comment: Can you show the relevant bits from urls.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the call to super's get_initial.  It's seems to use a class property instead of an instance property, causing you trouble.  Try this:

```
def get_initial(self):
    myobject = MyObject.objects.order_by('-code')[0]
    code = int(myobject.code) + 1
    initial={'code': str(code)}
    return initial
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have done the trick. Is this because the FormMixin is derived from 'object' rather than the thread-friendly generic.base.View? What do I need to be careful of when writing my own mixin classes?

Comment: I think that get_initial was not designed or tested enough, especially not tested to be called from it's overriding method.